# How to save Python web scraper output in JSON file format?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I recently started with coding and learning Python, and I am currently working on a web Scraper. I want to scrape data from multiple website and save it in JSON file format. So it is currently just printing out the search results. I want the website scrape data to be saved in JSON file. I am writing this code but getting an error of "is not JSON serializable". It is not writing in the filename file. Using Python 2.7.14 on Mac terminal. Below is the Scraper.py file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint
import re
import pyperclip
import json

urls = ['http://www.ctex.cn', 'http://www.ss-gate.org/']
#scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    #open the file "filename" in write ("w") mode
    file = open("filename", "w")
    json_data = json.dumps(my_list,file)
    #json.dump(soup, file)
    file.close()
```

I am using different code as well but still it is not writing in the filename file. Error "is not JSON serializable". Below is Scraper2.py file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint
import re
import pyperclip

urls = ['http://www.ctex.cn', 'http://www.ss-gate.org/']
#scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    #print(soup)

import json
# open the file "filename" in write ("w") mode
file = open("filename", "w")
#output = soup
# dumps "output" encoded in the JSON format into "filename"
json.dump(soup, file)
file.close()
```

Comment: Your `requests.get(url).content` returns you HTML documemt. What exactly do you want to save as JSON?

Comment: If you are trying to do web scraping in Python, you might want to look at https://scrapy.org/

Comment: @Andersson I want to save the content/information from website, interesting content which can be useful in search and recommendation engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In logical

your problem is a little ambiguous
Because I'm not sure you want to do request or parser?
Better not confuse them

### In technical

html format not perfectly fit json
I suggest two way to solve it

#### save each text as html file

you can save `response.text` (not `response.content`) to html file
like this

```
for url in urls:
    url = A_URL
    res = requests.get(url)
    html_file = open('FILENAME.html','w')
    html_file.write(res.text)
    html_file.close()
```

or

#### save multiple result to a single json file

```
out_list = []
for url in urls:
    res = requests.get(url)
    out_list.append(res.text)
json_file = open('out.json','w')
json.dump(out_list,json_file)
json_file.close()
```

and write another program to parse them

加油